# objective-c "mutating method sent to immutable object" error

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, immutability

I'm pretty new to objective-c and try to create a small app for the iphone.
I'm nearly done beside this little error here. Actually, I've searched hours with google to find a proper solution but unfortunately I'm not able to find a solution which works.
I'm using this tutorial here to build up an UITableView: [UITableView Tutorial](http://knol.google.com/k/usman-ismail/iphone-sdk-using-table-views/34oprzanmpe7q/6#)
The full error message looks like this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

This is the Data Controller Header:
MyLinksDataController.h

```
@interface MyLinksDataController : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *tableList; //<---important part

}

- (unsigned)countOfList;
- (id)objectInListAtIndex:(unsigned)theIndex;
- (void)addData:(NSString *)data; //<---important part
- (void)removeDataAtIndex:(unsigned)theIndex;

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSMutableArray *tableList; //<---important part

.....
```

And the Data Controller Method:
MyLinksDataController.m

```
#import "MyLinksDataController.h"

@implementation MyLinksDataController

@synthesize tableList;

- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        NSLog(@"Initilizing DataController");
        //Instantiate list
        NSMutableArray *localList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.tableList = [localList copy];
        [localList release];

        //Add initial Data
        [self addData:@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"];
        [self addData:@"BBBBBBBBBBBBBB"];

    }

    return self;

}
```

-------------------------------later on in the source code---------------------------------

```
- (void)addData:(NSString*)data; {

    [tableList addObject:data]; //<---- here the app crashes

}
```

I would pretty much appreciate any help.

Thank you for your support in advance.

Daniel

Answer (score 27):

Sending the *copy* message to an NSMutableArray -- as in the following statement in *init* -- returns an immutable copy.

```
self.tableList = [localList copy];
```

Cocoa documentation uses the word *immutable* to refer to read-only, can't-be-changed-after-initialization objects. Hence the subsequenct call to *addObject:* fails with an error message.

Note how the assignment statement above doesn't trigger any compiler warning. *copy* returns an *id*, which fits comfortably -- as far as the compiler is concerned -- in the NSMutableArray* tableList. There's no runtime error here either, as no messages get passed around; an NSArray pointer is just placed in an NSMutableArray pointer variable.

To obtain a mutable copy, use **mutableCopy** instead.

Note that both *copy* and *mutableCopy* create a new array and copy the content of the original to it. A change in the copy will not be reflected in the original. If you just need another reference to the original array, use *retain* instead.

You can find more detail in the discussion section of the [copyWithZone reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and in the [NSMutableCopying protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 5):

You're running into, basically, the memory management rules of Cocoa ([specifically, these details](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmImplementCopy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000049-999791)). If there is an object with an [immutable version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and a mutable version, then sending `-copy` to an object will return an immutable object.

Let's step through the relevant part.

```
NSMutableArray *localList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This creates a new, empty mutable array that you own. Fine.

```
self.tableList = [localList copy];
```

This creates an *immutable* copy of the empty array. Furthermore, you own this freshly created copy. That's two objects you own at the moment.

This also assigns your copied object to the `tableList` property. Let's look at the property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSMutableArray *tableList;
```

This property is declared with the [`copy` attribute](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW32), so whenever a new value is assigned to it, another `-copy` method is sent to it. This third copy, however, is not owned by you—it's owned by the object.

```
[localList release];
```

That releases the original empty mutable array. Fine, but there's still the one you made in the second line floating around, unreleased. That's a memory leak.

If you actually need a mutable copy of something, you want the `-mutableCopy` method. (The documentation for these methods is found under [`NSCopying`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying%5FProtocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSMutableCopying`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying%5FProtocol/Reference/Reference.html).) However, you're never going to get a mutable version of something into a property with the `copy` attribute, since it will send `-copy` to whatever it is assigned. Your property should use the `retain` attribute instead of the `copy` attribute, and the code to initialize it should look something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *localList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.tableList = localList;
[localList release];
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
self.tableList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

There's no need to copy anything in this situation, you're just creating a fresh object.

Comment: If a copy property is really called for, then substituting a retain property is going to be a poor solution. Since there is no mutablecopy keyword, declare the property as copy, but write your own accessor instead of using synthesized accessors.

Comment: Good point. I'd also throw in that I almost never see objects that advertise an `NSMutableArray` property. The purist in me would want to see a custom setter that stores a mutable copy of the object and a custom getter that returns an autoreleased immutable copy.

Answer (score 1):

If u are assigning localList from another object may be that is not Mutable in that case it can through this kind of error.

I hope it will be helpful.

```
self.tableList = [localList mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of mutableCopy i believe "`strong`" can also be used to tackle this problem. I had similar problem in my code as well because of using "`copy`" instead of "`strong`." So the below line:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *computers;
```

It should be:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *computers;
```

Hope it will be of immense help for beginners making mistakes like me.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the issue:

```
NSMutableArray *localList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.localList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:localList];
```